# Inserting a new node to a singly linked list doesnt work when i call the function in a loop

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, append, singly-linked-list

I am trying to **append** a node to the end of a list, so I wrote a simple `append_node` function. This function works fine normally but when I use a `for` loop , a extra node with a `undefined value` gets stored into the **head node**.

Here is the code:

```
int main() {
    linked_list *list;

    append_node(&list, 4);
    append_node(&list, 20);
    append_node(&list, 200);

    print_linked_list(list);    // 4 20 200
                                //prints just fine
}
```

the code above works fine but when I do this below:

```
int main() {
    linked_list *list;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        append_node(&list, i);

    print_linked_list(list);   // 11342689 0 1 2 3 4
                               // prints a extra undefined node here at the head 
}
```

expected result: `0 1 2 3 4`
actual result  : `11342689 0 1 2 3 4`

here is the `append_node` function:

```
void append_node(linked_list **head_ref, int value) {
    linked_list *current = *head_ref;

    linked_list *new_node = (linked_list *)malloc(sizeof(linked_list));
    new_node->node_value = value;
    new_node->next_node = NULL;

    if (*head_ref == NULL) {
        *head_ref = new_node;
        return;
    }

    while (current->next_node)
        current = current->next_node;

    current->next_node = new_node;
    return;
}
```

whenever I use a `loop` the list gets a **new head with a undefined value**.The rest of the list seems correct. I don't know why this happens. Can anyone please tell me?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should initialize the `linked_list *list` to `NULL`, and it should work just fine.

Comment: why does the code works properly when i do not use the loop  even if i dont initialize the list to NULL ?

Comment: It is mere luck or co incidence or maybe the work of OS.
I went a step ahead just to be sure. 
Here are the images of from when i tried to run it on my system:

https://imgur.com/064Uo8O
 https://imgur.com/goMgLB9

These images show seg fault, as list is not initialized to NULL, and my operating system (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS) randomly assigns it values which maybe illegal to access or something like that, and hence I get seg fault.

Now here's the ss when I initialize list to NULL and run

https://imgur.com/0j941UT

and believe me I have changed nothing, just initialized list to NULL.

Answer (score 1):

Variables with automatic storage duration are not initialized implicitly. Si in this declaration

```
linked_list *list ;
```

there is declared the pointer `list` with an indeterminate value.

As a result the program has undefined behavior.

You have to initialize the pointer explicitly like

```
linked_list *list = NULL;
```

Apart from this the function `append_node` could be defined simpler and more safer taking into account that the pointer `list` is passed by reference to the function.

Here you are.

```
int append_node( linked_list **head_ref, int value )
{
    linked_list *new_node = malloc( sizeof( linked_list ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->node_value = value;
        new_node->next_node  = NULL;

        while ( *head_ref != NULL )
        {
            head_ref = &( *head_ref )->next_node;
        }

        *head_ref = new_node;
    }

    return success;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `list` variable in `main` is uninitialized. The code has undefined behavior in both cases. Undefined behavior sometimes produces the expected behavior, sometimes not. The code generated for both functions is different, so it is possible that the location where `list` is stored happens to be a null pointer in the first case and not the second.

I'm afraid even compiling your program with extra warnings enabled (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror`) would not have caught this error.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct linked_list {
    struct linked_list *next_node;
    int node_value;
} linked_list;

void print_linked_list(const linked_list *list) {
    while (list) {
        printf("%d ", list->node_value);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

linked_list *append_node(linked_list **head_ref, int value) {
    linked_list *current = *head_ref;
    linked_list *new_node = malloc(sizeof(linked_list));
    if (new_node) {
        new_node->node_value = value;
        new_node->next_node = NULL;
        if (current == NULL) {
            *head_ref = new_node;
        } else {
            while (current->next_node)
                current = current->next_node;
            current->next_node = new_node;
        }
    }
    return new_node;   // if memory allocation failed, the function will return NULL
}

int main() {
    linked_list *list = NULL;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        append_node(&list, i);

    print_linked_list(list);
    return 0;
}
```